# GWT - setText and setValue not working for TextBox on initial load

Tags: events, gwt, textbox

I have a couple of text-boxes on a page where the user can enter some numeric values; however, try as I might, I can't fill those text-boxes with default values - specifically I would like `0.0` displayed in both upon page load.

Here is how I create them and what I have tried -

```java
GroupSection engineering_group = new GroupSection();
KSTextBox engrDesignTextBox  = new KSTextBox();
engrDesignTextBox.setWidth("2.875em");
//engrDesignTextBox.setWatermarkText("0.0"); ==> this works, but not what I need
//engrDesignTextBox.setText("0.0"); ==> this doesn't work
engrDesignTextBox.setValue("0.0"); // doesn't work either

KSTextBox engrScienceTextBox = new KSTextBox();
engrScienceTextBox.setWidth("2.875em");
//engrScienceTextBox.setWatermarkText("0.0"); ==> this works, but not what I need
//engrScienceTextBox.setText("0.0"); ==> this doesn't work
engrScienceTextBox.setValue("0.0"); // doesn't work either
```

I'm thinking that I need to attach an "onload" event listener and then try the setText in there?  That seems overkill for something that should be rather simple.

Incidentally, I have attached onBlurHandlers for both these text boxes and they work as expected (see code below)

The following code will simply insert`0.0` if the user clicks or tabs out of the text-box while it is EMPTY.

```java
engrDesignTextBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
      if(((KSTextBox)blurEvent.getSource()).getText().length() < 1) {
         ((KSTextBox)blurEvent.getSource()).setText("0.0");
      }
   }
});
engrScienceTextBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
     if(((KSTextBox)blurEvent.getSource()).getText().length() < 1) {
       ((KSTextBox)blurEvent.getSource()).setText("0.0");
     }
   }
});
```

**EDIT :** As requested here is how I have defined the setText and setValue methods in KSTextBox

```java
public class KSTextBox extends TextBox implements HasWatermark {
  .
  .
  . 

  @Override
  public void setText(String text) {
    String oldValue = super.getText();
    if(hasWatermark) {
      if(text == null || (text != null && text.isEmpty())){
        super.setText(watermarkText);
        addStyleName("watermark-text");
        watermarkShowing = true;
      }
      else{
        super.setText(text);
        removeStyleName("watermark-text");
        watermarkShowing = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      super.setText(text);
    }
    ValueChangeEvent.fireIfNotEqual(this, oldValue, text);
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(String value) {
    if(hasWatermark) {
      if(value == null || (value != null && value.isEmpty())){
        super.setValue(watermarkText);
        addStyleName("watermark-text");
        watermarkShowing = true;
      }
      else{
        super.setValue(value);
        removeStyleName("watermark-text");
        watermarkShowing = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      super.setValue(value);
    }
  }
```

So, getting back to the original question, how I do I initially set the values for these textboxes to `0.0`?

Comment: Can you post your code for `KSTextBox`?

Comment: @enrybo - I posted this code.

Comment: Sorry, can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That should have worked.Its very suprising.
 Is there a possibility that some other code is resetting the value after you did a setText or a setValue?
 Try debugging it in hosted mode.Put a breakpoint in setText and see when and how many times it is getting invoked

Comment: I haven't figured out how to debug the part of my application that defines the UI.  It is using GWT defered-binding.  It's a nightmare.  I'm using Tomcat 7 for my localhost servlet container and Maven to do my builds and my IDE is IntelliJ. What is hosted mode?  Can I run "hosted mode" for the development environment described above?

Comment: I have used this in eclipse. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideHostedMode

Comment: My apologies :) Yes this is the latest https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging